# Let $ a$ be a fixed natural number. Prove that the set of prime divisors of $ 2^{2^{n}} + a$ for $ n = 1,2,\cdots$ is infinite

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, contest-math, recreational-mathematics

$\textbf{Question:}$Let $ a$ be a fixed natural number. Prove that the set of prime divisors of $ 2^{2^{n}} + a$ for $ n = 1,2,\cdots$ is infinite.

I have come to know that this problem easily follows from "Kobayashi's theorem". But that probably won't give any points on a contest-math situation.

Apart from that,
I think we would need to somehow use the idea behind the Euclid's proof of infinitude of primes. But it seems too tricky. I could hardly make any progress in this problem. So, any kind of hint or solution is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h275813p1492629 is a solution that does not relly on Kobayashi's theorem. Also it seems to be from Iran TST 2009-Day1-P2.

Comment: I have already seen that solution.But sadly I couldn't understand it properly.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose with fixed number a we get a composite of the form $N=2^{2^n}+a$ which has some prime divisors. If we prove that these composites are infinitely many then we can conclude that the number of prime divisors of N for a fixed a is infinite(this is what the question is asking, if I understood it correctly).

I found this theorem in a number theory book by Sierpinski. The proof is by A. Schintzel.

Theorem: For every natural number $k ≠ 1$ there exists infinitely many natural numbers like n such that number $2^{2^n}+k$ is composite.

Proof:

Let a be an arbitrary natural number and k an integer unequal to unity.Take $k-1=2^s h$ where $2^s$ is the greatest power of $2$ which divides $k-1$ and h is an odd number which can be positive or negative. Take m such that $2^{2^m}>a-k$ and number t such that $t≥s$ and also $t≥m$. If $2^{2^t}+k≥2^{2^m}+k> a$ is composite, then we have a composite number in the form  $2^{2^n}+k$ greater than a. So we assume $p=2^{2^t}+k$ is prime. Since $t≥s$ and $k-1=2^sh$, then we have:

$p-1=2^{2^t}+k-1=2^sh_1$

where $h_1$ is a positive odd number.Now due to Euler's theorem we have:

$2^{\phi(h_1)} ≡ 1 \ mod (h_1)$

Since $p-1=2^s h_1$, then:

$2^{s+\phi(h_1)}≡ 2^s \ mod (p-1)$

Since $t≥s$ , we get:

$2^{t+\phi(h_1)}≡ 2^t \ mod (p-1)$

Finally due to Fermat's little theorem we have:

$2^{2^{t+\phi(h_1)}}+k ≡ 2^{2^t}+k≡ 0 \ mod (p)$

Since $2^{t+\phi(h_1)}> 2^t$ then we may write:

$2^{2^{t+\phi(h_1)}}+k>2^{2^t}+k=p$

Hence number $2^{2^{t+\phi(h_1)}}+k$ will be a composite greater than a, because:

$p=2^{2^t}+k≥2^{2^m}+k > a$

The proof is done.

Comment: I confess that I haven't followed your answer that closely.
Therefore, analysis inside of your answer may have already 
answered this question.  If I understand correctly, you
have proven that if k is fixed and n ranges over the integers,
then the sequence $2^{(2^n)} + k$ has an infinite subsequence
of composite numbers.  This is not the same thing as saying
that there is an infinite sequence of primes such that each
prime divides at least one element in the corresponding *composite* 
infinite subsequence.  Perhaps I am missing something. ...see next comment

Comment: Continuing in the same vein (again, perhaps I simply haven't analyzed your answer closely enough), nor is it the same thing as saying that there is an infinite sequence of primes such that each prime divides at least one element from the sequence formed by $2^{(2^n)} +k.$

Comment: @user2661923, thanks for your attention and comment. I edited my answer. I hope it answers your question.

Comment: I tried to look at your answer in more detail.  In the first paragraph of your edited answer you say "...then we can conclude that the number of prime divisors of N for a fixed a is infinite..."  You have focused on the critical point of my previous comments.  How do you know this?  It didn't seem like the excerpt that I am quoting is subsequently proven in your answer.  **Am I mistaken**, is the quoted excerpt proven in your answer?  If not, is there a theorem that I am unaware of that justifies the assertion in the excerpt that I am quoting?  ... see next comment

Comment: The **rebuttal assertion** (that must be refuted) is that **although** there are an infinite # of composites of the required format, there exists a **finite** list of primes such that the prime factorization of each of the pertinent composites involves no prime numbers other than the ones in the finite list.

Comment: @user2661923, how do you say"there exist a finite list of primes....". could you show that or give a reference to show that?

Comment: I can't give a counter example that is necessarily consistent with your infinite list of composites; in fact, assuming that the original assertion is both true and proven, I would surmise that no such counter example is possible.  I am simply playing devil's advocate.  For example, consider the finite list of all primes under 100.  Obviously, an infinite # of distinct composite #'s can be formed each of whose prime factorization only involves these primes under 100. ...see next comment

Comment: If my logic is correct, then you would have to analyze the prime factorization of each of the pertinent composites as you create them and add them to the (eventually) infinite list.  If I'm not mistaken, you would have to (somehow) demonstrate that you are continually able to add a composite to the list whose prime factorization contains at least one prime # that is **missing** from the prime factorizations of **all** of the preceding pertinent composites in your list. ...see next comment

Comment: Perhaps I am begging the following question (re I didn't scrutinize your proof closely enough): If P is the largest prime # involved in the prime factorizations in your composites at any given point, is there a way of **guaranteeing** that you can add a new pertinent composite that must have at least one prime factor greater than P?

Comment: @user2661923, your logic is correct. But I am not at the level to analyze the prime factorization of each composite. May be a member of this site could do that. I suggest you ask it in another question.